# Como eu faço para que uma query só rode em momentos específicos?

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, postgresql

Oque está acontecendo: Eu fiz um código que puxa a quantidade de vendas do meu banco de dados

```
$iniMes = date('2021/05/08 08:00:00');
$iniMes1 = date('2021/05/08 22:00:00');
 $qMigras = pg_query($conexao241, "SELECT COUNT(ceil(id_carga)) FROM public.smart_chamadas_discador
 WHERE datahora_geracao >= '$iniMes' AND datahora_geracao <= '$iniMes1'
 AND status_chamada= 'Atendida' ");
 $lista = pg_fetch_assoc($qMigras);
   $migras = intval(current($lista));
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <?php echo $migras ?>
   </body>
 </html>
```

mas toda vez que alguém acessa esse front essa query executa novamente no server e isso acaba pesando o servidor. Queria saber alguma forma de fazer com que essa query execute uma vez a cada meia hora e no front só apareça aqueles dados mesmo que sejam de meia hora atrás.

conexão:

```
$servidor = "10.131.167.240";
$usuario = "cliente";
$senhaDB = "minhasenha";
$dbname = "dbcallcenter";
$port = 5432;

$conexao241 = pg_connect("host=$servidor port=$port  dbname=$dbname user=$usuario password=$senhaDB ");
```

obs: sou novo em php.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Sua pergunta é extremamente dificil de responder de uma forma prática pois existem inúmeras soluções que podem ser implementadas para resolver esse problema. Melhor do que dar downvote como alguns fizeram eu prefiro te ajudar, mas veja não há uma resposta mais adequada para o seu problema.

**Cache de resultados**
Essa pode ser uma forma realmente eficiente para você conseguir fazer o que precisa, para o php existem boas bibliotecas, como redis, memcached.

O fluxo seria assim, o sistema verifica se há um cache válido, se houver exibe o resultado armazenado em cache para o usuário. Caso não haja cache válido o sistema realiza a query e armazena o resultado em cache e apresenta para o usuário.

Nas configurações do cache você pode definir o tempo de duração do cache. Mas saiba que esses métodos só deveriam ser usados se o dado a ser exibido não precisa estar o tempo todo atualizado ou não recebe muita atualização. Então para uma tela que exiba dados de vendas não seja uma boa idéia, pois isso costuma mudar com frequência.

aqui tá um tutorial: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/memcached-with-php/

**Por que não faz sempre a query?** Sistemas como esses não tem muito para onde fugir, provavelmente é melhor você sempre executar a query para uma informação como essa, os sistemas de banco de dados modernos estão preparados para uma alta demanda, claro que isso dependerá muito do seu servidor e da eficiência do seu código. Procure usar queries simples e eficientes e usar indicies onde houver relacionamento entre tabelas.